# Why html tags are not rendered in laravel sent email?

Tags: laravel

Sending email with

```
\Mail::to(
```

method in laravel 8 app
I have html tags in im my email template

```
@component('mail::message')
    <h3 >
         You registered at {{ $site_mame }}
    </h3>


    Best regards, <br>
    ...
@endcomponent
```

and code in my app/Mail/UserRegistered.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class UserRegistered extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $site_mame;
    public $user;
    public $confirmation_code;

    public function __construct( $site_mame, $user, $confirmation_code )
    {
        $this->site_mame = $site_mame;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->confirmation_code = $confirmation_code;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('email.UserRegisteredEmail')
                    ->with('site_mame', $this->site_mame)
                    ->with('user', $this->user)
                    ->with('confirmation_code', $this->confirmation_code);
    }
}
```

With sendgrid options in my .env file I got valid emaul at my google account, but html tags are not rendered.
If there is a way to render all html tags? Does it depend on laravel app/emailing options
or setting in my google(or some other account).
What can I do from my side?

**UPDATED :**
Modified :

```
$this->view(
```

I got error :

```
No hint path defined for [mail]. (View: project/resources/views/email/UserRegisteredEmail.blade.php)
```

Pointing to my blade file.
Searching in net I found as possible decision :

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

and clearing all cache

But I still got the same error.
Did I miss some options ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you intending to render this as a regular view (HTML) instead of a markdown template?

Comment: I think blade supporting html tags

Answer (score 0):

You are using the markdown() method, which is a method to utilize the pre-built templates and components of mail notifications in your mailables.

This offers a multitude of advantages:

- instead of wrapping headings in h1, h2, etc. tags, you can just put a #, ##, etc. at the beginning of the line
- no need to wrap lists in `<ul>`, and list items in `<li>` tags. In markdown, you can just use a dash (`-`) for listing elements
- italic/bold font can be achieved by putting `*`/`**` around the text you want to emphasize

You can read more about this on the official Laravel documentation.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#markdown-mailables

If you want to use HTML, you can just render a view:

```
    /**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('email.UserRegisteredEmail')
                ->with('site_mame', $this->site_mame)
                ->with('user', $this->user)
                ->with('confirmation_code', $this->confirmation_code);
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at Modified